# Any full Eclipse skin available?

Tags: eclipse, ide, skin

Since I have some ocular problems and my eyes start bleeding when the display is too bright, I was wondering if there is any full Eclipse skin available.
I already found darker theme for the code perspective but not for the entire IDE.

Thanks

**UPDATE** : You can now find the Moonrise theme on the Eclipse MarketPlace.

Comment: Not sure but [`f.lux`](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) might help.

Comment: It does actually thanks, even though it's really weird at first.

Comment: Wow, f.lux the single most useful tip I found on here. With we had the option to give +100 sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a plugin [here](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/index.html) that lets you create and use skins for eclipse as you want (colours and everything).